# How to make a basement warmer?

Tags: basement, renovation

I'm looking for some cheap way to renovate my basement and make it warmer and quiter,any ideas?

Comment: This question is overly broad. For example the project stealing construction materials, starting a basement tire fire, and allowing the occupants to breath the fumes for an extended period could result in a cheap, warm, quiet renovation. Please provide additional details regarding project scope and location.

Answer (score 1):

I helped a friend of mine renovate his basement. We installed [these raised floor tiles](http://www.homedepot.com/p/DRIcore-7-8-in-x-2-ft-x-2-ft-Aspen-Subfloor-Panel-CDGNUS750024024/202268752) with carpet and pad over them. This made the floor much warmer, especially when going barefoot.

We also put up 2"x4" wall frames around the perimter wall (along with some interior walls) and insulated them. Then we drywalled over them. This reduced the floor area slightly, but it was worth it.

The basement is now typically warmer than the main floor. However, all moisture issues need to be reolved correctly first, or you'll have issues with the wall system.